# How I do I make a bookmark in google chrome the select the element ID of a radio button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I want to make a bookmarklet that click the Id value of a radio button on [this page](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) I want it to select - Option 2

I've created a bookmarklet in google chrome and used this code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mat-radio-2-input')[1].checked = true
```

but when I click the bookmark, it does nothing I want it to select "Option 2" elementId.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page you can see that Option 2 has id `mat-radio-3-input`, you can use this code to select it via a bookmark:

```
javascript:(function() {  var radioButton = document.getElementById('mat-radio-3-input'); if (radioButton) {    radioButton.checked = true;  } else {    alert('Radio button not found.');  }})();
```

Comment: OMG it worked! thank you so much. your a genius!